# REACT how to re-fetch to update state to re-render component

Tags: reactjs, use-effect, react-state, rerender

i have this `itemCard.jsx` component:

```
  ItemCart({item}) {
   ... 
  const { user } = useContext(AuthContext);
  const [isAdded, setIsAdded] = useState(false);
```

`isAdded` state to check if the user already added the item to his shopping cart and it assumes not `false` as user logging in for the first time

```
  return (
  ...
      <button
        type="button"
        className="addToCart"
        onClick={() => handleCart(item._id)}
      >
        {isAdded ? "REMOVE FROM CART" : "ADD TO CART"}
      </button>
  ...
)
   ...
}
```

the button value should say `add to cart`, and when the user clicks it, it will trigger `handleCart` function :

```
  const handleCart = async (itemId) => {

    const response = await fetch(
      `http://localhost:8000/add-or-remove-item-from-cart/${itemId}`,{ method: "POST",headers: {"Content- 
     type": "application/json",}, body: JSON.stringify({userId: user._id}),});
    const data = await response.json();

    setIsAdded(!isAdded);
  };
```

which makes request to `/add-or-remove-item-from-cart/${itemId}` and checks if user added this item to his cart it will remove it, otherwise it will add it, for the first time when user clicks `add to cart` the button value becomes `remove from cart` as `isAdded` state changes to `true` and this works fine

but `useEffect` must needed to persist state when a new `item` is added to shopping cart:

```
  useEffect(() => {
    setIsAdded(user.cartItems.includes(item?._id));
  }, [item?._id, user, user.cartItems]);
```

but when i refresh the page, the state refreshes and the button value backs to `add to cart`, when i console logged `user`, i found out the problem is `user` state for `AuthContext` will be the value before the user added any items to `user.cartItems`, and it won't change until until i update the data on `AuthContext` therefore `localStorage`, how to do that?

Comment: You'll have to fetch every time you reload. The browser / client has no idea what the user did last time and I assume you don't want to store user data in something like `localStorage`.

Comment: ```user``` is stored in ```localStorage``` in ```AuthContext``` ... ```useEffect(() => { localStorage.setItem("user", JSON.stringify(state.user));
}, [state.user]);```

Comment: but even with that, as you said the browser has no idea what the user did, so the user data won't get updated on ```localStorage```, so yes i need a way to fetch every time the user add or remove an item to get the data updated right?

Comment: which means i need to update the data on the localStorage itself